# Silverlight data in matrix

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, matrix

Does anyone know how to arrange some data to a data matrix? A simple example:

For example the model would be the following:

```
public class SampleItem 
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int DayOfMonth { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to have a `List<SampleItem>` displayed in data matrix something like

```
DayOfMonth | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ...
---------------------------- ...
Category1  |   | 7 |   |   | ...
Category2  | 2 |   | 5 |   | ...
Category3  | 1 | 6 | 5 | 1 | ...
```

So in the intersection of rows and columns it would display sum of Value where DayOfMonth = Column name and Category = row name.

Is it possible to have this? Maybe with non-static rows for categories and by any chance in a datagrid to enable grouping?

Comment: Not sure if DataSet is available in Silverlight but if it is that would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since DataSet is not available within Silverlight you could use this [DataSet](http://silverlightdataset.net/silverlightdataset/Default.aspx) perhaps just the DataSet type within that framework as it is geared towards something else. Once you have a table like structure you could simply walk the data or poll the data and define your sums as needed.